Confusion on Definition of Weighted Sobolev space
I have been reading a little bit about weighted Sobolev spaces, and I have found myself with the following quandary: The norm of the unweighted sobolev space, $W^{1,p}$ is defined as$$
\left(\int |f(x)|^p dx+\int |\nabla f(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}
$$however in this paper (and in any paper I have found about the topic) they define the weighted $W^{1,p}$ norm as $$
\|f\|_{W^{1,p}(\omega)}=\left(\int |f(x)|^p\omega(x)dx\right)^{1/p}+\left(\int |\nabla f(x)|^p\omega(x)dx\right)^{1/p},
$$in other words, the renormalization by raising to $1/p$ happens before summation whereas in the standard sobolev space applies it after, i.e. I would have expected $$
\|f\|_{W^{1,p}(\omega)}=\left(\int |f(x)|^p \omega(x)dx+\int |\nabla f(x)|^p\omega(x)dx\right)^{1/p}.
$$What is the reason for this, and why would this choice matter for proving compact embedding theorems?

They are equivalent, in the sense of equivalence of norms

fair enough, thank you

Let $s,t\in [0, \infty )$ and $\gamma \in (0, 1]$. By this inequality, $(s+t)^{\gamma} \leq s^{\gamma} + t^{\gamma}$. On the other hand, as the function $\phi :[0, \infty ) \to [0, \infty )$ defined by $\phi (x) := x^{\gamma}$ is increasing, $s^{\gamma} + t^{\gamma} \leq 2(s+t)^{\gamma}$. By setting $s = \int |f(x)|^{p} \omega (x) \, {\rm d}x$, $t = \int |\nabla f(x)|^{p} \omega (x) \, {\rm d}x$ and $\gamma = 1/p$, it follows that the two norms are equivalent.
It is straightforward to verify that if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are Banach spaces, $T:Y\to Z$ is a compact operator and $S:X\to Y$ is a bounded linear operator, then $T\circ S$ is a compact operator. As the norms are equivalent, the identity mapping of $W^{1,p}$ equipped with one norm onto itself equipped with the other norm is an isomorphism, and as a result any compact embedding of $W^{1,p}$ does not depend on which of these two norms are used.

Excellent, I appreciate it.
